# Python Ldap: get user email address

Tags: python, ldap

How do I print email address of a user using CN.

I am able to print the CN and mail, but not just been able to print e-mail address only.

```
email = ldapconn.search_s(member, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,'(objectClass=*)',['mail'])
```

Output:

```
[('CN=FirstName LastName,OU=Users,OU=Developers', {'mail': ['Firstname.Lastname@mail.com']})]
```

I only need the value of the mail to be printed. Expected Output:

```
Firstname.Lastname@mail.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to *get it by index*:

```
email[0][1]['mail']
```

Or, in case of multiple results:

```
[result[1]['mail'] for result in results]  # the 0-th item of a result is always a DN
```

where:

```
results = ldapconn.search_s(member, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,'(objectClass=*)',['mail'])
```